# Contact form 7 Hide response messages after 5 seconds

Tags: ajax, plugin-contact-form-7

I just installed this plugin and I must say it does everything I need.

I am using a custom made popup div with a CF7 inside it.

I need to hide response messages (error, success message) after 5 seconds. Is that possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use below code to hide message

```
// Contact Form 7 submit event fire
document.addEventListener('wpcf7submit', function(event) {
  setTimeout(function() {
        jQuery('form.wpcf7-form').removeClass('sent');
        jQuery('form.wpcf7-form').removeClass('failed');
        jQuery('form.wpcf7-form').addClass('init');
  }, 1000);

}, false);
```

Answer (score 0):

I would like to use css than:

```
.wpcf7-form.sent .wpcf7-response-output {
  animation: hideresp 5s forwards; 
  animation-iteration-count: 1;
}

@keyframes hideresp {
  90% { opacity:1; }
  100% { opacity:0; }
}
```